# How to view Instant Messages on the Microsoft Office Communcation Server 2007

Tags: ocs, ucma

In Microsoft Live Communication Sever, all the IMs (instant messages) are stored on MS-SQL database and I could see them by simple queries.

I've activated message Archiving on the Microsoft Office Communication Server 2007.

Are all IMs stored on databse? If yes, how can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By activating Archiving Service in OC, I could query the Archive database. Now I can see all messages.